# How to access at request attributes in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Currently I use:

```
<%
final String message = (String) request.getAttribute ("Error_Message");
%>
```

and then

```
<%= message %>
```

However I wonder if the same can be done with EL or JSTL instead of using a scriptlet.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

EL expression:

```
${requestScope.Error_Message}
```

There are several implicit objects in JSP EL. See [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) under the ["Implicit Objects"](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043) heading.

Comment: That `requestScope` is by the way optional. The `${Error_message}` will scan in all scopes, in order of page, request, session and application and return the first match.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the hint. But I probably keep the requestScope anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I provided a new one now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used Client client = new Client(); client.setName("María"); request.setAttribute("client", client); and in my jsp page I used ${ client.name } and It wroks fine.

Answer (score 4):

Using JSTL:

```
<c:set var="message" value='${requestScope["Error_Message"]}' />
```

Here **var** sets the variable name and **request.getAttribute** is equal to **requestScope**. But it's not essential. ${Error_Message} will give you the same outcome. It'll search every scope. If you want to do some operation with content you take from **Error_Message** you have to do it using **message**. like below one.

```
<c:out value="${message}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just noting this here in case anyone else has a similar issue.
If you're directing a request directly to a JSP, using Apache Tomcat web.xml configuration, then `${requestScope.attr}` doesn't seem to work, instead `${param.attr}` contains the request attribute `attr`.

Comment: `param` is request parameter NOT attribute. These are 2 different things.