# Cannot get attribute (in request scope) set by Servlet and forwarded to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I tried several solution even here on StackOverflow but none seems to work:
I want to pass a string from a Servlet to a JSP and show it with EL.

I created a simple plain project on Netbeans and this is the code I added:

Servlet Code:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String message = "Hello";

    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
```

JSP Code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2 style="border: 2px solid brown; width: 20%"> Message is: ${message} </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

What get me frustated is that even for the documentation (Oracle Api Reference and a HeadFirst O'Reilly Guide) this should be straightforward, but I simply get no text, even if I use a scriptlet. I tried both Glassfish and TomEE

Comment: The sample works fine. Are you using any Filter?

Comment: @ZakiMak Nope. I barely know what they are for.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you. It will help hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am more or less certain your problem is that your Servlet is not being invoked. Put a console(System.out.println) output in your Servlet and see if the output is printing.

**Do not try to access the JSP page directly.** Rather hit the URL mapped for your Servlet.

Your Servlet can be mapped in two ways:
1. Annotation
2. Deployment Descriptor (web.xml)

```
@WebServlet("/processForm") 
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // implement servlet doPost() and doGet()...
}
```

In the case above if you hit **/processForm** relative to your webapp the UploadServlet will be called and any processing by the Servlet will be carried out and forwarded if dispatcher is used.

A descriptor equivalent is shown below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bla.bla.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/processForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I just realized I stupidly didn't call the servlet name, but only the App root. You Sir, have my sincere Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ${message}, try using ${requestScope.message}

(Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912797/1843508)

Comment: Been there, done that. Didn't work. Besides the framework default search for that name in several implicit objects included requestScope