# c:forEach does not seem to find the list in request scope

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm learning how to use Java Servlets and I've setup a toy example.

I have a `servlet` with the following logic in the `doGet` method:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        List theList = new ArrayList();
        theList.add(1);
        theList.add(2);
        theList.add(3);
        request.setAttribute("intList", theList);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp");        
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Then I have the following code in `hello.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Redirect Worked</h1>
<c:forEach items="${intList}" var="item">
    ${item}<br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect my browser to show:

```
Redirect Worked
1
2
3
```

But all I see is:

```
Redirect Worked
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a long time since I used jsp's, but don't you need to include the jstl library in the jsp? `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912690/how-to-access-at-request-attributes-in-jsp

Comment: A combination of both of your suggestions fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
    <c:forEach items="${intList}" var="item">
        <c:out value="${item}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DaveH, theodosis and Chaim I fixed my JSP file:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>redirect worked!</h1>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${requestScope.intList}">
        <c:out value="${item}"/>
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```