# How to read form parameter data using JSP without using scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, jstl-functions

I want to read the form parameter data using scriptlet in #jsp. But i do not want to use any java code in JSP. Then do i need Expression Language or #JSTL or what?

Comment: Maybe you want El Expressions ? check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912797/3353241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noting this here in case anyone else has a similar issue.
If you're directing a request directly to a JSP, using Apache Tomcat web.xml configuration, then `${requestScope.attr}` doesn't seem to work, instead `${param.attr}` contains the request attribute attr.