# Rewriting getAttribute() scriptlet as a JSTL in JSP/HTML?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, scriptlet, getattribute

I have a scriptlet within my JSP page that gets an attribute "username" passed from a previous serlvet.  The scriptlet validates if the "username" attribute was set, if not it denies access to homepage and instead redirects to the login page:

```
<%
    String validUser = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
    if (validUser == null){
    session.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Access Denied:  Please login to access this page");
    session.setAttribute("username", "");
    response.sendRedirect("LoginFormError.jsp");
        }
%>
```

Since scriptlets in JSP/HTML code is not ideal, how do I go about re-writing this scriptlet as a JSTL instead?

**EDIT**:

Ok, so far here's what I've got:

```
<c:set var="validUser" value='${param.username}' />

<c:if test = "${validUser == null"}   
   <c:set var="errorMsg" value="${'Access Denied:  Please login to access this page'}"/>
   <c:set var="username" value=""/>
   <c:redirect url="LoginFormError.jsp"/>
</c:if>
```

Are the getAttribute() and setAttribute() done right?

Answer (score 0):

Good to see you doing this, You can do using the `jstl/core` taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:if test="${sessionScope.username == null}">
    <c:redirect url="LoginFormError.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: I did an edit before I saw your answer.  I'm wondering if `${param.attr["username"]}` is equivalent to `getAttribute("username")`?

Comment: I thought the `username` was a session variable as per your original post.  Why don't you try what I have posted?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Sorry about that, I was following a JSTL guide that had `attr` as the session variable.  Yes, `username` is my correct variable.

Comment: What's the difference between `${param.username}` and `${sessionScope.username}`?  A contributor suggests using `param` according to his answer here (2nd answer):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912690/how-to-access-at-request-attributes-in-jsp/44677068

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding i.e. `username` would be part of the queryString, **but** your question posted it as `String validUser = (String) session.getAttribute("username");` which is a session variable.  Only **you** can say which is correct.  But anyway, please modify my answer as per your requirements.

Comment: Er, James what's happening?