# getting a blank page as output in my web browser when I run the following servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jspdf, servlet-3.0

I am getting blank page as output in my web browser when I run DemoServlet

note : I have used both doGet and doPost methods in my servlet instead of service method even though I am getting the same output.

The below is the following code

```
public class Student_Class {

    int RollNo = 0;
    String Name="";
    
    Student_Class(int RollNo,String Name) {
        this.RollNo = RollNo;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    
    public int getRollNo() {
        return RollNo;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    
}
```

the above is my StudentClass

I have created a servlet like below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        Student_Class Student = new Student_Class(1,"Name1");
        request.setAttribute("Student", Student);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        
    }
}
```

and my jsp file is below the name of my jsp file is : display.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix= "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        
    ${Student}
</body>
</html>
```

my web.xml file is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSTL_Demo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Demo</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Demo</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Demo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DemoServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DemoServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DemoServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using tomcat 10.0.10 as my server and eclipse as my IDE

please help me I am a beginner and I don't know much about jsp and servlets correct me if I have done anything wrong

[click here to see the output on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v22u9.png)

[click here to see the project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMdL1.png)

Comment: What is location of display.jsp?

Comment: Define 'I am getting null'.

Comment: When doing `request.setAttribute("xxx", ...)`, access it as `${requestScope.xxx}` or `${requestScope['xxx']}` - [see here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912690/how-to-access-at-request-attributes-in-jsp).

Comment: @user207421 null in the sense I am getting a blank page as my output

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thankyou for your suggestion but still I am getting a blank page as the output I have attached a image in my question please check it

Comment: @Loc for your reference I have attached an image of the project explorer hope you find it helpful

Comment: Try /display.jsp and see if it work. OR put display.jsp into WEB-INF folder then try /WEB-INF/display.jsp

Comment: @Loc I am getting the following message : JSP file [/display.jsp] not found.  when I kept the display.jsp into  WEB-INF folder

Comment: If you put display.jsp into WEB-INF, you have to use this path:  /WEB-INF/display.jsp

Comment: Don't touch service method, use doGet instead

Comment: @Loc actually I want to forward the request and response to display.jsp from DemoServlet using Request Dispatcher and I want to pass the Student object from DemoServlet to display.jsp file and want to print the hashcode of the Student object in the web browser which was passed by the DemoServlet to display.jsp

Comment: @Loc thanks for your suggestion to use doGet method even though I am using doGet method I am getting the blank page

Comment: @Loc yes I am using /WEB-INF/display.jsp path when I use this path I am getting 404 error BTW thanks for your time